# JavaFx. Login Page link to next page

Tags: java, javafx

I really need help here. I'm new into this `gui` and `javaFx`. I've been doing this coding but don't know how to link it. Both of my codes is working properly. the idea is, when sign in button is clicked the source code 2 will appear. but now, I do the source codes on different class. please help me. thanks

My source code 1 :

```
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.HPos;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.FontWeight;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Win10
 */
public class ProjectFlower extends Application {

    private static final double WindowWidth  = 600;
    private static final double WindowHeight = 400;
    Button B1;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        primaryStage.setTitle("Flowerstyle Net");

        GridPane GP = new GridPane();
        GP.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        GP.setHgap(10);
        GP.setVgap(10);
        GP.setPadding(new Insets(10,10,10,10));
        GP.setPrefSize(WindowWidth,WindowHeight);
        GP.setMinSize(WindowWidth,WindowHeight);

        ColumnConstraints left = new ColumnConstraints();
        left.setHalignment(HPos.RIGHT);
        left.setHgrow(Priority.NEVER);

        ColumnConstraints right = new ColumnConstraints();
        right.setHgrow(Priority.ALWAYS);

        GP.getColumnConstraints().addAll(left,right);

        Text text = new Text("\t\t\t\t WELCOME TO FLOWERSTYLE NET" + "\n\n\t\t\t\t\t " + "ENJOY YOUR SHOPPING!! :)");
        text.setFont(Font.font("SHOWCARD GOTHIC", FontWeight.NORMAL,20));
        GP.add(text,0,0,2,1);

        GridPane.setHalignment(text,HPos.LEFT);

        Label L1 = new Label("User Name");
        GP.add(L1,0,1);

        Label L2 = new Label ("Password");
        GP.add(L2,0,2);

        TextField TF1 = new TextField();
        GP.add(TF1,1,1);

        TextField TF2 = new TextField();
        GP.add(TF2,1,2);

        Button B1 = new Button ("Sign in");
        GP.add(B1,1,3);
        GridPane.setHalignment(B1,HPos.CENTER);

        GP.setStyle("-fx-background-color : grey");

        Scene scene = new Scene(GP,WindowWidth,WindowHeight);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Source code 2 :

```
import java.awt.TextArea;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CusInfo extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    //final Button button = new Button("Proceed");
    //final Label notification = new Label ();
    final TextField TF = new TextField("");
    final TextArea TA = new TextArea("");

    String address = " ";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage){
        stage.setTitle("Customer Information");
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(new Group(),450,250);

        final ListView LV = new ListView();
        LV.getItems().addAll(
        "ROSE",
        "TULIPS",
        "LILY",
        "CARNATION",
        "LAVENDER",
        "ORCHID",
        "SUNFLOWER",
        "LILAC",
        "HYACINTH",
        "DAISIES",
        "FORGET ME NOT",
        "PRIMROSE",
        "CAMELLIAS",
        "CHERRY BLOSSOM",
        "BIRD OF PARADISE"
        );

        final ComboBox CB1 = new ComboBox();
        CB1.getItems().addAll(
        "WHITE",
        "BLUE",
        "RED",
        "PURPLE",
        "BLACK",
        "YELLOW",
        "ORANGE"
        );

        final ComboBox CB2 = new ComboBox();
        CB2.getItems().addAll(
        "ENGLAND",
        "AMSTERDAM",
        "MALAYSIA",
        "ICELAND",
        "AUSTRALIA"
        );

        CB2.setValue("MALAYSIA");

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setVgap(4);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));

           Label name = new Label ("Customer Name:");
           pane.add(name,0,0);
           TextField nameField = new TextField();
           pane.add(nameField,1 , 0);

           Label OrderID = new Label ("Order ID:");
           pane.add(OrderID, 0, 1);
           TextField OrderField = new TextField();
           pane.add(OrderField,1 ,1 );

           Label date = new Label ("Date:"); 
           pane.add(date,0,2);
           TextField dateField = new TextField();
           pane.add(dateField,1 , 2);

           Label phoneNum = new Label ("Phone Number:");
           pane.add(phoneNum,0,3);
           TextField phoneField = new TextField();
           pane.add(phoneField,1 , 3);

           pane.add (new Label ("Type of Flower:"),0,4);
           pane.add(LV,1,4);
           //TextField flowerField = new TextField();
           //pane.add(flowerField,1 , 4);

           pane.add( new Label ("Flower Colour:"),0,5);
           pane.add(CB1,1,5);
           //TextField colourField = new TextField();
           //pane.add(colourField,1 , 5);

           pane.add( new Label ("Origin:"),0,6);
           pane.add(CB2,1,6);
           //TextField originField = new TextField();
           //pane.add(colourField,1 , 6);

           Label quantity = new Label ("Quantity:");
           pane.add(quantity,0,7);
           TextField quantityField = new TextField();
           pane.add(quantityField,1 , 7);

           Label totalPrice = new Label ("Total Price:");
           pane.add(totalPrice,0,8); 
           TextField priceField = new TextField();
           pane.add(priceField,1,8);

           Label address = new Label ("Customer Address:");
           pane.add(address,0,9);
           TextField addressField = new TextField();
           pane.add(addressField,1 , 9);

           Button button = new Button("Proceed");
           pane.add(button, 1, 10);

           Group root = (Group)scene1.getRoot();
           root.getChildren().add(pane);
           stage.setScene(scene1);
           stage.show();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is switch scenes.

1) Take all of the code from your second class and convert it to a class that has a method that returns that next scene.

```
import java.awt.TextArea;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CusInfo
{
    //final Button button = new Button("Proceed");
    //final Label notification = new Label ();
    final TextField TF = new TextField("");
    final TextArea TA = new TextArea("");

    String address = " ";

    public Scene getScene()
    {
        Scene scene1 = new Scene(new Group(),450,250);

        final ListView LV = new ListView();
        LV.getItems().addAll(
        "ROSE",
        "TULIPS",
        "LILY",
        "CARNATION",
        "LAVENDER",
        "ORCHID",
        "SUNFLOWER",
        "LILAC",
        "HYACINTH",
        "DAISIES",
        "FORGET ME NOT",
        "PRIMROSE",
        "CAMELLIAS",
        "CHERRY BLOSSOM",
        "BIRD OF PARADISE"
        );

        final ComboBox CB1 = new ComboBox();
        CB1.getItems().addAll(
        "WHITE",
        "BLUE",
        "RED",
        "PURPLE",
        "BLACK",
        "YELLOW",
        "ORANGE"
        );

        final ComboBox CB2 = new ComboBox();
        CB2.getItems().addAll(
        "ENGLAND",
        "AMSTERDAM",
        "MALAYSIA",
        "ICELAND",
        "AUSTRALIA"
        );

        CB2.setValue("MALAYSIA");

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setVgap(4);
        pane.setHgap(10);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5,5,5,5));

           Label name = new Label ("Customer Name:");
           pane.add(name,0,0);
           TextField nameField = new TextField();
           pane.add(nameField,1 , 0);

           Label OrderID = new Label ("Order ID:");
           pane.add(OrderID, 0, 1);
           TextField OrderField = new TextField();
           pane.add(OrderField,1 ,1 );

           Label date = new Label ("Date:"); 
           pane.add(date,0,2);
           TextField dateField = new TextField();
           pane.add(dateField,1 , 2);

           Label phoneNum = new Label ("Phone Number:");
           pane.add(phoneNum,0,3);
           TextField phoneField = new TextField();
           pane.add(phoneField,1 , 3);

           pane.add (new Label ("Type of Flower:"),0,4);
           pane.add(LV,1,4);
           //TextField flowerField = new TextField();
           //pane.add(flowerField,1 , 4);

           pane.add( new Label ("Flower Colour:"),0,5);
           pane.add(CB1,1,5);
           //TextField colourField = new TextField();
           //pane.add(colourField,1 , 5);

           pane.add( new Label ("Origin:"),0,6);
           pane.add(CB2,1,6);
           //TextField originField = new TextField();
           //pane.add(colourField,1 , 6);

           Label quantity = new Label ("Quantity:");
           pane.add(quantity,0,7);
           TextField quantityField = new TextField();
           pane.add(quantityField,1 , 7);

           Label totalPrice = new Label ("Total Price:");
           pane.add(totalPrice,0,8); 
           TextField priceField = new TextField();
           pane.add(priceField,1,8);

           Label address = new Label ("Customer Address:");
           pane.add(address,0,9);
           TextField addressField = new TextField();
           pane.add(addressField,1 , 9);

           Button button = new Button("Proceed");
           pane.add(button, 1, 10);

           Group root = (Group)scene1.getRoot();
           root.getChildren().add(pane);

           return scene1;
        }
    }
```

2) In your first class, the Application, you need to set an event handler on the login button.

```
// rest of code...

Button B1 = new Button ("Sign in");
        GP.add(B1,1,3);
        GridPane.setHalignment(B1,HPos.CENTER);

B1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            // change scenes here
            changeScenes();
        }
    });

// rest of code...
```

3) Keep a reference to the primaryStage in the first class:

```
private Stage primaryStage;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    primaryStage.setTitle("Flowerstyle Net");

   // rest of code...
}
```

4) Create the changeScenes method in the first class

```
private void changeScenes()
{
    CusInfo ci = new CusInfo();
    Scene scene = ci.getScene();

    // set new title
    primaryStage.setTitle("Customer Information");

    // change the scene on the stage
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
}
```

If you make all the changes, then you should get the desired result.

Good luck :)